# ROS Navigation help

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone.
I have been reading about ROS navigation lately and I came to know that we need to explore the whole map ourself in order to build it up. What I'm trying to achieve is that, to do the same without actually exploring it, I have the image of a map with all the dimensions from obstacles(say), so can we do this? Also the map is 3D.
Regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241953/ros-navigation-help/) by [silverbullet](https://answers.ros.org/users/27197/silverbullet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-08-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes you can do that.
I would look into the map_server package: http://wiki.ros.org/map_server which takes a predefined map and enables it for navigation. It also defines how the image format should be.
Most of the navigation algorithms (amcl, etc) use a 2D map, so you probably should convert it to 2D.

---

Originally posted by [FOXTER](https://answers.ros.org/users/26976/foxter/) with karma: 153 on 2016-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0